# Symfony 4 translation files in directories

Tags: symfony, internationalization, translation, symfony-4.2

I want to save translation files in directory, for example:

```
      /translations/admin/messages.en.xlf
      /translations/admin/validation.en.xlf
      /translations/client/messages.en.xlf
     /translations/client/validation.en.xlf
```

And how to use these translations in Controllers and Twig templates ?

Answer (score 4):

> **Translation Resource/File Names and Locations**
>
> Symfony looks for message files (i.e. translations) in the following
> default locations:
>
> - the translations/ directory (at the root of the project);
> - the Resources/translations/ directory inside of any bundle.

The locations are listed here with the highest priority first. That

> is, you can override the translation messages of a bundle in any of
> the top two directories.
>
> The override mechanism works at a key level: only the overridden keys
> need to be listed in a higher priority message file. When a key is not
> found in a message file, the translator will automatically fall back
> to the lower priority message files.

<sup>*Source: https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations*</sup>

And later on the same page / chapter

> You can add other directories with the paths option in the
> configuration:
>
> *config/packages/translation.yaml*
>
> ```
> framework:
>     translator:
>         paths:
>             - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations/admin'
>             - '%kernel.project_dir%/translations/client'
> ```

You can use those as any other translation files, remembering the overriding mechanism quoted here above

*Full reference: https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/translation.html*